# Add UILabel over UIImage inside StackView

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

[image]

The part of my storyboard looks like on first photo. On second photo I present constraints. What I am trying to achieve is to put UILabel at the bottom over the UIImageView (with photo "DJI_0049").

Comment: When you say “over the UIImageView”, do you mean you want them to overlap? Or do you mean you want the label to be closer than the image view to the top edge of the screen?

Comment: Overlap, this is like a title of some news. Over the image with reduced alpha in order to see the part of the photo in the background.

Comment: Using StackView, You can't do this.

Comment: I manage to do this using stack views but don’t know how to post it here as a answer on my own question

Answer (score 1):

Add the label to the same view as the `UIStackView`.. such that they are siblings/adjacent views. Add the imageView to the stackView and then constrain the label to the imageView.

Since they are siblings it WILL work. Do note that the label CANNOT be an arranged sub-view of the stackView.. otherwise broken constraints will be the result.

Example:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  TestSO
//
//  Created by Brandon on 2018-02-28.
//  Copyright © 2018 XIO. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let label = UILabel()
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        let otherView = UIView()
        let otherView2 = UIView()

        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.distribution = .fill

        self.view.addSubview(stackView)
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(otherView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(otherView2)


        label.text = "Hello World"
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
        otherView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        otherView2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor),
            stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor),
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.centerXAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.centerYAnchor),
            label.leftAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: imageView.leftAnchor),
            label.rightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: imageView.rightAnchor),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: imageView.topAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: imageView.bottomAnchor)
        ])


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            otherView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            otherView2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0)
        ])
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t overlap views like this in a stack view.

Your best option is to use normal auto layout constraints to lay out one of the views (probably the image) and then either use a stack view or constraints to layout the views that you want over it.

Answer (score 0):

With a `UIStackView` **this will not work** (for as far I know `UIStackView`?!). But it can be easily achieved with the following constraints:

Set leading, top and trailing edges from the `UIImageView` to his superview. Define some height for the `UIImageView`.

Secondly, set leading and trailing edges from the UILabel to the `UIImageView`. Make sure the `UILabel` and `UIImageView` share the same superview.

Lastly, set the bottom of the `UILabel` to the bottom of the `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

i was also able to do this in a stackview by adding the label as a subview to the image view.

[image: screen grab from simulator with below constraints]

```
        cell.avatarImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.cellBodyStackView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        cell.avatarImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.cellBodyStackView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        cell.avatarImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.cellBodyStackView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        cell.avatarImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.commentLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        cell.avatarImage.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: cellWidth * 0.25).isActive = true

        cell.avatarImage.addSubview(cell.usernameLabel)
        cell.usernameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.avatarImage.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        cell.usernameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.avatarImage.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        cell.usernameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.avatarImage.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        cell.usernameLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.avatarImage.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        cell.usernameLabel.textAlignment = .center
        cell.usernameLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        cell.usernameLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
```